# How to replace /home/ubuntu/... in cs50 IDE

Tags: c, ide, filepath, cs50

I am trying to write a program in C within a file pointer, but the problem is I only managed to write the file path like this:

`char *line = gtline("/home/ubuntu/games/cards-against-humanity/black-cards/single/1/file1.txt", 3);`

but I would like to replace `/home/ubuntu/games` with something else so I can download the whole directory `/cards-against-humanity` and the program still points to the file `/file1.txt`.

I've tried with `/~` and with `/.` but it gives me Segmentation fault I suppose when the program trys to open the file.

Thanks in advance.

Update: gtfile function is a function i created by myself here's the declaration:

```
char *gtline(char *s, int i) 
{
    FILE *file;

    char *filename = s;
    static char buffer[MAX_LINE];

    int read_line = i;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    bool keep_reading = true;
    int current_line = 1;
    do
    {
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, file);

        if (current_line == read_line)
        {
            keep_reading = false;
        }
        if (feof(file))
        {
            keep_reading = false;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
        }

        current_line++;

    } while (keep_reading);
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Which `getline` function are you using? The [POSIX function getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) takes different arguments. The manpage from [CS50](https://manual.cs50.io/3/getline) tells the same.

Comment: Please describe what you want to do. "Write a program in C within a file pointer" does not really make sense. Please edit your question to also add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you are doing.